# How do I set the SalesTerm for a Customer with QuickBooks_IPP?

Tags: php, quickbooks-online

I'm successfully adding a Customer to QuickBooks using QuickBooks_IPP, but I'm having difficulty setting the sales term for the customer. I've looked through the documentation and cannot find examples of setting the SalesTerm.

I've added these lines to the example code, but does not throw an error and does not add the sales term.

```
    $Term = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesTerm();
    $Term->setSalesTermRef(2); //15 days
    $Customer->setSalesTermRef($Term);
```

This is the full Customer add code:

```
    // Set the IPP version to v3 
    $IPP->version(QuickBooks_IPP_IDS::VERSION_3);

    $CustomerService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_Customer();

    $Customer = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Customer();
    $Customer->setTitle('Ms');
    $Customer->setGivenName('Shannon');
    $Customer->setMiddleName('B');
    $Customer->setFamilyName('Palmer');
    $Customer->setDisplayName('Shannon B Palmer ' . mt_rand(0, 1000));

    //set days due
    $Term = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesTerm();
    $Term->setSalesTermRef(2);
    $Customer->setSalesTermRef($Term);

    // Phone #
    $PrimaryPhone = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryPhone();
    $PrimaryPhone->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
    $Customer->setPrimaryPhone($PrimaryPhone);

    // Mobile #
    $Mobile = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Mobile();
    $Mobile->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
    $Customer->setMobile($Mobile);

    // Fax #
    $Fax = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_Fax();
    $Fax->setFreeFormNumber('860-532-0089');
    $Customer->setFax($Fax);

    // Bill address
    $BillAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_BillAddr();
    $BillAddr->setLine1('72 E Blue Grass Road');
    $BillAddr->setLine2('Suite D');
    $BillAddr->setCity('Mt Pleasant');
    $BillAddr->setCountrySubDivisionCode('MI');
    $BillAddr->setPostalCode('48858');
    $Customer->setBillAddr($BillAddr);

    // Email
    $PrimaryEmailAddr = new QuickBooks_IPP_Object_PrimaryEmailAddr();
    $PrimaryEmailAddr->setAddress('support@consolibyte.com');
    $Customer->setPrimaryEmailAddr($PrimaryEmailAddr);

    if ($resp = $CustomerService->add($Context, $realm, $Customer))
    {
        print('Our new customer ID is: [' . $resp . ']');
    }
    else
    {
        print($CustomerService->lastError($Context));
    }
```

I can query for the Customer after the add but it does not return the SalesTerm as I would expect. Do I need the SalesTerm Service instead of the Object?

Answer (score 1):

The only time you'd wrap something in an object like you're doing with `QuickBooks_IPP_Object_SalesTerm` is if it's actually a full nested node in the XML request.

i.e. if you saw this in Intuit's documentation:

```
<Customer>
  ...
  <SalesTermRef>
    <Id>...</Id>
    ... other nested tags inside here ...
  </SalesTermRef>
  ...
</Customer>
```

Then you would have been on the right track.

But per Intuit's docs, this is only a normal non-nested node:

```
<SalesTermRef>4</SalesTermRef>
```

So just use the `->setSalesTermRef($val)` method:

```
// Terms (e.g. Net 30, etc.)
$Customer->setSalesTermRef(4);
```

Sometimes the easiest way to see this stuff is to examine the XML output. Look at what you're sending with:

```
print($CustomerService->lastRequest());
```